# Should CSS3 gradients be applied using background-image or just background?

Tags: css, gradient

When using CSS3 gradients, should we be using `background-image` or just `background` to apply them?

eg:

```
background: #CCC;
background: -moz-css3-gradient-code;
background: -webkit-css3-gradient-code;
```

or

```
background: #CCC;
background-image: -moz-css3-gradient-code;
background-image: -webkit-css3-gradient-code;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends.

This:

```
background: #CCC;
background: -moz-css3-gradient-code;
background: -webkit-css3-gradient-code;
```

will *replace* the background colour with the gradient. Whilst this:

```
background: #CCC;
background-image: -moz-css3-gradient-code;
background-image: -webkit-css3-gradient-code;
```

will keep the background colour there, and render the gradient above it.

I think the default behaviour with gradient backgrounds is for the browser to fill the element’s area with them, so in the second example, by default, the background colour would be hidden by the gradient. But `background-size` can change that, and gradients can be transparent or translucent (via `rgba` colours).

So it depends whether you want the background colour to still be there be behind the gradient, in browsers that support the gradient.

Comment: Cool! Thanks Paul. Wasnt as straight forward as I thought, but all makes sense now. Cheers!